# How to setup css linting in Vue.js project with auto-correction

Tags: css, vue.js

Is there any way to lint `<style>` segment in `.vue` file during coding? I setup `eslint(with airbnb ruleset)+prettier` for `<template>` and `<script>` sections(with some auto-correction on save) but I can't do anything with style section.
How to get for example this

```
.range-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 5px 8px 0;
}
```

from this

```
    .range-color {
    display: inline-block;
       width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;

margin: 5px 5px 8px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution) I used `stylelint` from [This post](https://medium.com/@brtjkzl/linting-css-in-vue-files-6bb20faac0f2), without 'processor'(it's deprecated).
Add `stylelint` and `stylelint-config-standard` packages to your project (you may use `yarn` instead of `npm`):

```
npm i --save-dev stylelint stylelint-config-standard
```

Create `.stylelintrc` in the main directory with the following content:

```
{
 "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
}
```

For putting some files to ignore list create `.stylelintignor` and add them(syntaxis same as `.gitignor`)

As a result, Stylelint will lint and fix(depends on editor settings) `.css` files and `<style>` segment in `.vue` files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Prettier` extension of Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I thought it uses for js/ts linting. I have it but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you take a look at the details, `Prettier` also formats `Vue`, `CSS`, `SCSS` and it'll save your time xD

Comment: Okay, in the settings.json, add `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, and it will format your files when you save.

Comment: or Go to File->Preferences->Settings. In search field type, `formatOnSave` and check the `Editor: Format On Save` checkbox.

Comment: "editor.formatOnSave": true is deprecated now it looks like this "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    // For ESLint
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
    // For Stylelint
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  } . But still it do notihing to css segment in vue file. Hm maybe i need to add some rule file to project...

Comment: It's not deprecated. See [official documentation](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#format-on-save), and [this blog](https://scottsauber.com/2017/06/10/prettier-format-on-save-never-worry-about-formatting-javascript-again/)

Comment: I use it every day without any problem.

Comment: where Prettier takes rules for style segment?

Comment: I that blog nothing about linting CSS in .vue file. I also use prettier+eslint(Airbnb ruleset) for template and js code) But problem is with linting/formatting CSS in .vue sile)